# cannot get remote repository refs in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, version-control, egit

Introduction:

Main Repo: `Repo1`.
After forking it, my repo is : `ForkedRepo1`

In Eclipse-Git, I cloned my `ForkedRepo1`.
Until Thursday, I was able to commit & push without any issue.

Then suddenly, on Thursday, I got the error:

```
Cannot get remote repository refs
Reason:
ssh://<forkedrepo1: session.connect:
java.netSocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I have a SSH key.

Nothing as altered in my system, so I am not sure what happened.

To make matters worse, I deleted my Remote(origin) in eclipse-git and when I try to add it back, I get the same error - `java.net.SockettimeoutException: Read timed out`.

However, via `git bash`, I can commit a file and push it to the local branch in GitHub.

I hope this info is enough to give me some idea.

FYI: I am working on a existing project, so when I push a file up for review, it worked successfully. It is just that I cannot now do it in eclipse.

Comment: I set timeout to 3000 - it came with an error saying it cannot connect connect to any repository.... (when trying to commit and push my files).

Answer (score 0):

Then try, as [described here](http://rgordon.co.uk/blog/2012/01/06/egit-connection-timed-out/), to switch to an HTTPs URL.

[image: http://rgordon.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/EGitSSHConfig.bmp]

You can then cache your GitHub credentials (GitHub username/password) in a credential helper, generally already configured (see `git config credential.helper`)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by the [removal of weak cryptographic standards](https://github.com/blog/2507-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed).
You need a recent Java 8 revision (i.e. 1.8.0_161), a recent version of EGit (such as 4.10.0.201712302008-r) and you probably need also to restart (just once) Eclipse with the `-clean` parameter.

Comment: No, the OP is using SSH. What you are referring (TLSV1 being not supported anymore) is involved with HTTPS URL.

Comment: GitHub also removed diffie-hellman-group1-sha and diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, impacting on SSH.